# Open browser tab to multiple IP addresses if each goes to the same domain

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

I have a domain that has multiple servers behind a load balancer.  I would like to "fire off" a web browser to each IP address but using this same domain name.

My use case is Moodle, but the same happens for WordPress and various other software platforms.

Let's say the domain is www.example.com, and the ip addresses are

192.168.1.5
192.168.1.6
192.168.1.7
192.168.1.8
192.168.1.9
192.168.1.10

If I go to any of these IP addresses as itself, then the software platform redirects me to www.example.com, DNS kicks in, and I generally end up with 6 browser tabs to the same IP address.

I can edit my /etc/hosts file, but again that tends to work only with the first IP address loaded.

In my case the OS is Ubuntu and the browser is Firefox or chromium-browser, but if a solution exists for Mac or Windows or a different browser I can also run with them.

With regard to sessions, each tab should be running the domain www.example.com with a different IP address and different session.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why are you actually trying to do this?

Comment: We have a number of Moodle servers (front end and back end) and I want to test each server is running OK and also test page load times

Comment: For "is it ok" your LB should probably be able to handle probes. What you want to do isn't possible with a single machine without some secondary tools to help like a proxy that rewrites your requests or similar.

Comment: We already have server checks for "is it alive" but those don't include user sso login, presenting user with page, timing page loads etc. I'd like to do this from a browser but could set up a separate server I guess.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the answer I have come up with is to use a docker environment with a docker compose copying an `/etc/hosts` file per container where the dns entries for each domain are pointing to one of the servers for testing (one container -> one ipv4 or ipv6 address).

I could then run Silenium on each container, but to keep it simple I am using python requests to log into the server and scrape the page to see if it has in error or all is good.

Each container outputs to a log file in a local volume labelled for the IP address being tested.

This can then be run on any linux host or even my workstation to see for example whether one of the servers is glitching after a deployment.